# ForgeViewer: How to find Z world-coordinate where z-section is placed

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I am trying to find z-value of world-coordinates where z-section cuts the model. I assumed that it is in values returned from 'getState()' but it I wasn't able to figure it out.

I also checked API documentation of Viewer v7 but I couldn't find any function that helps.

Could anyone help me? Perhaps some other trick to get the 'viewing box' after sectioning is applied?

Thanks
Bandu

Answer (score 0):

Try `getCutPlanes` - see its doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getcutplanes):

```
viewer.getCutPlanes()
//[n.Vector4]0: n.Vector4 {x: 0.5455882464475988, y: 0, z: 0.8380533785733665, w: 2.9219428579920317}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. In my case (Viewer v7), I am getting values: x=0, y=0, z=1 regardless of where z-section is, but 'w' parameter changes with the height of the cut-plane. Does that mean z=1 means 'z-section' and 'w' actually refers to the z-coordinate of the cut?

Comment: Not exactly sure if that or something else is the case until we look into the model - can you upload it to a sharing service (e.g. weTransfer/GDrive/Dropbox etc) and send the link to forge.help@autodesk.com with a brief description of the issue and we will go from there

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I got an answer from Xiaodong. I think I am okay for now.